# Apache Accumulo role assignment

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, accumulo, nosql

I'm adding Accumulo to my Cloudera cluster.
How should I assign roles.
I have 4 servers currently running.

1 Server: HDFS Name Node, HDFS Secondary Name node, HDFS Balancer, Activity Monitor, Cloudera Management Services, Spark Gateway, Spark History Server, Yarn Job History Server, Yarn Resource Manager, Zookeeper Server
3 Servers: HDFS Data Node, Kafka Broker, Spark Gateway, Yarn Node Manager, Zookeeper Server

Cloudera wizard asks for assignment of the following Accumulo roles: Master, Tablet Server, Garbage Collector, Monitor, Tracer, Gateway.

Is it OK if Tablet Server role is assigned to all HDFS Data Nodes and all other roles to first server?
Is there a sense to assign Accumulo Gateway to the same nodes as Tablet Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, running the Accumulo Master, Garbage Collector, Monitor, and Tracer on the first server and running TabletServers on the others make sense.

I'm not sure what the "Accumulo Gateway" is; Apache Accumulo has no such component/service called "Gateway".